# What is the difference between CREATE TABLE tblname AS SELECT... vs. CREATE TABLE tblname(....) USING <format> LOCATION '...'

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet

```
The table data path: /mnt/data/account_transactions
Database: office
Table (to be created): ACCOUNT_TRANS (Accounts Transactions)
```

Can anyone please confirm if my understanding is correct, else please explain the differences between the two approaches.

Approach 1)

```
CREATE TABLE office.account_trans
AS
SELECT * FROM parquet.`/mnt/data/account_transactions`
```

Approach 2)
If we know the fields in account_trans:
AccountId, AccountName, TransactionAmt, BalanceAmt

```
CREATE TABLE office.account_trans (
  AccountId STRING, 
  AccountName STRING, 
  TransactionAmt DOUBLE, 
  BalanceAmt DOUBLE
)
USING parquet
LOCATION '/mnt/data/account_transactions'
```

**My Understanding:**
Approach 1) Here the Select query is first executed and then the table is created on the result of the just executed select query.

So any new records added to the /mnt/data/account_transactions will not get reflected in office.account_trans table.

Approach 2) Since here we have given the LOCATION clause as /mnt/data/account_transactions, so any new additions/deletions/updates will get reflected in office.account_trans

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as per the docs, the LOCATION clause implies EXTERNAL, so new data may be read without explicitly inserting it in Spark. That being said, you may need to refresh the cache to have the metastore read the updated information.

Comment: When you say refresh cache to have the metastore read the updated info, we need to do the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <tablename>` command, right ?

Comment: For partitioned tables, yes. Also thinking as per docs here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html#refreshTable-java.lang.String-. If you are using databricks, then I think there can be some additional caching that you may need to manage, but I'm not certain.